Librephotos (and other apps) doesn't show dashboard after installation
I'm trying to install LibrePhotos with Docker on my remote server (running Arch Linux) and I am following the official guide
After cloning the repo, and modifying the .env file with the correct paths, I ran docker-compose up -d and everything seems to be fine
However, the docs say

You should have LibrePhotos accessible after a few minutes of boot-up on localhost:3000

but if I do ssh -L 3000:127.0.0.1:3000 myuser@myserver -N -v and open 127.0.0.1:3000 I don't see anything. It doesn't work with localhost:3000 either. However, I don't think it's an ssh problem: if via ssh in my server I try to ping 127.0.0.1:3000 (or localhost) I get ping: 127.0.0.1:3000: Name or service not known.
What I have tried already

Full clean install of docker running

# Stop all containers
docker stop `docker ps -qa`

# Remove all containers
docker rm `docker ps -qa`

# Remove all images
docker rmi -f `docker images -qa `

# Remove all volumes
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf)

# Remove all networks
docker network rm `docker network ls -q`


Trying another project with a web dashboard to see if this one was the problem, but it is the same with PhotoPrism


I am running

Docker version 26.0.0, build 2ae903e86c
Docker Compose version 2.26.1

